# Roblox Studio ReplicatedFirst:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen() throws RoactCompat.RoactTree from studio

Tags: lua, roblox, roblox-studio

That's the weirdest problem I ever got in Roblox Studio. I have a LocalScript parented with ReplicatedFirst, and the problem is at

```
script.Parent:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen() --ReplicatedFirst:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen()
```

it throws the following error and I think we can't do anything to fix that:

> CorePackages.Packages._Index.RoactCompat-9c8468d8-8a7220fd.RoactCompat.RoactTree:130: attempt to index nil with 'root'

It has never thrown this weird error before, but after (in the information in the output) it prints this:

Stack Begin  -  Studio

14:24:55.628  Script 'CorePackages.Packages._Index.RoactCompat-9c8468d8-8a7220fd.RoactCompat.RoactTree', Line 130 - function unmount  -  Studio - RoactTree:130

14:24:55.628  Script 'LoadingScript', Line 1024 - function handleRemoveDefaultLoadingGui  -  Studio

14:24:55.628  Script 'LoadingScript', Line 1058 - function handleFinishedReplicating  -  Studio

14:24:55.628  Stack End  -  Studio

I changed its position, replaced

```
script.Parent:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen()
```

with

```
local rf = game:GetService("ReplicatedFirst")

rf:RemoveDefaultLoadingScreen()
```

but with no success. I suppose that it is a Studio problem and could be fixed or just me who forgot where to put it in the script because I also tried to change its location in the script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is fine. Both samples worked for me. I think this is likely a temporary problem that Roblox will probably fix soon. Getting the latest version from https://www.roblox.com/create might take care of it

Comment: @Kylaaa I hope it is a temporary bug that I have because of that the custom loading screen I made is pointless

Comment: I reinstalled studio and it worked. I think it is because a file was corrupted